# AutoMapper Opt and Dest

Tags: c#, automapper

When should `opt`, `x`, or `dest` be used?

Take for example:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<NewTask, Task>()
       .ForMember(x => x.Users, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

I see example expressions written with different combinations of `opt`, `x`, or `dest`. Is there a convention?

Comment: use whatever you like, there is no convention.

Comment: That is surprising, thank you.

Comment: For those wondering what opt stands for, it stands for `options`. It is first mentioned here: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, no convention. Sometimes I use "dest" sometimes "d" sometimes "x". Usually a "d", though.